# .NET IIS 64 bit association to Visual Studio 32bit projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, 32bit-64bit

Im not experienced with how Internet information Services (IIS) handles hosting of applications and how different bit version of Visual Studio effect hosted applications.

Let me use a practical example: if I were to create a ASP Web Application in Visual Studio 32 bit, and host the application on a version of IIS that is in 64 bit mode, would the application be run in the 64 bit environment and be able to use all the allocated resources, or would the fact that the application was created in a 32bit version of Visual Studios, limit the application when run in IIS, regardless of the configurations of IIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't host Windows Forms Application in IIS. The question itself is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. If I change the question to an ASP Web Application, would it then apply?

Comment: Then the following solution will apply:

IIS depends on OS architecture. if your OS is 64 bit, you can support both 32 bit and 64 bit. For 64 bit OS, by default, IIS runs on 64 bit and supports almost all managed assemblies compiled even for 32 bits. It won't support mixed / unmanaged assemblies. You can always force 64 bit IIS to run in 32 bit with help of application pool or through command line.

If IIS is in 32 bit, it won't support 64 bit assemblies. All traditional managed and unmanaged assemblies will be supported.

Comment: Thanks. So if I compiled a project under Visual Studio 32bit, IIS will be able to award the project the ability to use 64bit?

Comment: Or put differently, the size of addressable memory of a version of Visual Studio has no impact on the amount of memory addressable by an application hosted by IIS?